# Calculation of conditional probability distribution

Tags: conditional-probability

Can you help me to formulate and solve the following question?

What is the probability of picking a rich person from the whole population
where prior probabilities are equal and conditional probabilities are:

```
            P(Rich|Male)= 0.3     
          P(Rich|Female)= 0.4
```

Thanks.

Comment: Suppose the population has 100 people, 50 males and 50 females. How many males are rich? How many females are rich? How many _people_ are rich? Then see if you can figure out the answer to the question you are seeking help with. Next, repeat for the case of 200 people, 100 males and 100 females. Then try other numbers, e.g. 1000 people etc. Do you see a pattern? If not, take an average of all the answers you get.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Then can I say P(rich)= P(Male|Rich)+ P(Female|Rich) ? where P(male|rich)= P(rich|male).P(male)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand probabilities, and besides, you don't know the numbers P(Male|Rich) and P(Female|Rich), do you? And before you rush to respond that you do too know these numbers, read _very carefully_ your question and note that what you have told us are the values of P(Rich|Male) and P(Rich|Female) which are not quite the same thing. Why don't you try to work on the simpler things I suggested in my previous comment?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I was thinking that I can find P(Male|Rich) by multiplying P(Rich|Male) and P(Male) from the bayesian formula. And then P(Female|Rich) with the same way. Isn't this true? I will end up with the same solution P(rich)= 0.35

Comment: It sounds like you're saying P(Male|Rich) = P(Rich|Male) $\times$ P(Male) ... but that's not so

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability

Comment: I don't think this process is converging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean by "prior probabilities are equal" that P(Male)=P(Female)=0.5, then the solution is simple.

P(Rich) 
= P(Rich and Male) + P(Rich and Female)
= P(Male)P(Rich|Male) + P(Female)P(Rich|Female)
= (0.5)(0.3) + (0.5)(0.4)
=0.35